# categorise data from large spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a script that will create a table from a spreadsheet with a list of suppliers. The spreadsheet has over a thousand entries, so my script is processing it very slowly. Here is the code

```
function SupplerAnalysis() {
 //Importing data
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 //Creating a sheet
 if (ss.getSheetByName("Analysis") !=null) {
 //Logger.log('exists');
 } else {
 //Logger.log('Creating new');
  ss.insertSheet("Analysis");
 }
 var sheetNumber = ss.getSheetByName("Analysis").getIndex() - 1;
 ss.getSheetByName("Analysis").clear(); 
 var newsheet = ss.getSheets()[sheetNumber];
 var newdata = newsheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 newsheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue('Suppliers');

 //Get list of suppliers
 for (var s = 1; s < data.length; s++) {
 var supplier = data[s][3];
 var z = 1;
 newdata = newsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   for (var r = 1; r < newdata.length;r++) {
      if (supplier === newdata[r][0]) {
          z = 2;
      } else { Logger.log(r);}
    }
   if (z === 1) {
       newsheet.getRange(r+1, 1).setValue(supplier);
   } else if ( z > 1 ) { Logge.log('Error');
   }
  }
```

Column data[s][3] is the list of suppliers for different jobs. There are more than thousand entries, and about 160 suppliers in total. This script takes about 5 minutes to execute, which is very slow and ineffective.

How can I change the code to speed up this process? 
Is there any way to get the output from the NewCategoryFilter in to a table?

Comment: To mark a post as solved you have to simply 'accept' , it will grant 15 reps to the answerer. Editing the title is not a common usage on this platform.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I am new here :)

Comment: Also Srik, thanks to you too for corrections :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't call the API in loops:

```
function SupplerAnalysis() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newsheet;

  if ((newsheet=ss.getSheetByName("Analysis")) == null) 
    newsheet = ss.insertSheet("Analysis");
  else newsheet.clear();

  var supplierList = [['Suppliers']];

  for (var s = 1; s < data.length; s++) {
    for (var r = 1; r < supplierList.length; r++)
      if (data[s][3] == supplierList[r][0]) break;
    if (r == supplierList.length) supplierList.push([data[s][3]]);
  }

  newsheet.getRange(1,1,supplierList.length,1).setValues(supplierList);
}
```

Keep your eyes open on typos - I just typed this in.

Converting suppliers in object keys could be somewhat risky as the supplier names maybe are not legal object keys.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. This is perfect. Object keys worked as well, but if you say it's risky, I will use this. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the call to newsheet.getDataRange inside your loop will probably speed things up. You can check for duplicates faster by storing values as object {} keys and using the "in" operator to see if they are present. e.g.

```
var set = {};
vals.forEach(function(value){
    if(value in set) {
        console.log('duplicate found');
    }
    set[value] = true;
});
```

I'm not sure what NewCategoryFilter is.

Comment: "Getting rid of the call to newsheet.getDataRange inside your loop will probably speed things up."
I know, but without it in "for (var r = 1; r < newdata.length;r++)" the newdata.length gives the wrong output. There is no data before loop is complete.
I will try using object keys and see how it goes. Thanks a lot for the reply.

Comment: This worked very well. The list is generated in a matter of seconds. Thanks a lot.